# Python Matching images with OpenCV + AirCV + ADB. Coordinates retrieved are wrong despite matching

Tags: python, android, opencv, adb, image-recognition

So what i'm doing is essentially taking a screenshot of my emulator using ADB then matching the screenshot with a specific image. If the image can be found in the screenshot then it returns "True" along with the coordinates.

Functions used
Check if image can be found in the screenshot:

```py
def get_curr_device_screen_img_byte_array(self,device):
    return device.screencap()

def check_any(self, device, *props_list):
    imsch = cv2.imdecode(np.asarray(self.get_curr_device_screen_img_byte_array(device), dtype=np.uint8),
                     cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

    for props in props_list:
        path, size, box, threshold, least_diff = props
        # x0, y0, x1, y1 = box

        imsrc = cv2.imread(path)

        result = aircv.find_template(imsrc, imsch, threshold, True)

        if result is not None:
            return True, result['result'] ### the result['result'] are the coordinates

    return False, None
```

Clicking in emulator with ADB

```py
def tap(self,x,y,device):
    cmd = 'input tap {} {}'.format(x, y)
    str = device.shell(cmd)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Actual main program:

```py
cancelcheck, cancelcheckpos = self.check_any(device,[r'images\cancelcheck.png',(960,540),(0, 0, 0, 0),0.90,25])
print(cancelcheckpos)
if cancelcheck:
    self.tap(int(cancelcheckpos[0]),int(cancelcheckpos[1]),device)
```

However that self.tap is not clicking at all in the image & when checking the coordinates with cancelcheckpos it returns (888,598), which is extremely weird because the emulator max size is currently 960x540 so 598 height just shouldn't exist since the original image it's being compared with (the device.screencap()) ain't even that big to begin with.

I also have looked around for people doing similar things and it seems everyone does it the same way I do and generally they just use the coordinates returned by the aircv.find_template and it works for them, somehow for me it isnt at all.